# Set active class to owl carousel center item

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

I am using owl carousel for a slider. Used the following code

```
<div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="carousel slide multi-item-carousel" id="theCarousel">
                    <div class="carousel-inner">

                    </div>
                    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
                    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

The items are coming from instagram manually. Here's the jquery code

```
$('.carousel-inner').instahistory({
      get: '#hashtag', // or @username
      template: '<div class="item"><a href="{{link}}" data-toggle="lightbox"><img src="{{image}}"></a></div>'
    });
```

Slider is not showing the items. I think the problem is the missing of an active class. If I add the active class in the template , it considers every item as active. So I want only the center item as active and changed when left or right arrow is clicked.
The library I used doesn't have the same functionality as instafeed.js . Also instafeed doesn't support getting hashtag contents anymore. Can't use that now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Instagram - Bootstrap 3 carousel with instafeedjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30345493/instagram-bootstrap-3-carousel-with-instafeedjs)

Comment: The library I used doesn't have the same functionality. I think this doesn't solve my problem. Also instafeed doesn't support getting hashtag contents anymore. Can't use that now.